# Include gatsby helmet script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet, helmet.js

I can't include a script in helmet gatsby.
The script I want to include is this:

```
  <script src = "assets / vendor / jquery / jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

I tried doing this and the console gives me an error:

```
 import Helmet from "react-helmet";
    import {withPrefix} from "gatsby";
    
    <Helmet>
    <script src = {withPrefix ('masonry.js')} />
    </Helmet>
```

with this syntax I also tried and it gives me an error:

```
<Helmet>
  <script src = "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type = "text / javascript" />
</Helmet>
```

**How would it be solved?**

Comment: What is the error? _ gives me an error_ is not really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a lot of stuff there. If your assets are internal, like the one you have in the first and second snippet, add it in your `/static` folder and import it like:

```
import { withPrefix } from "gatsby"
// ...

<Helmet>
    <script src={withPrefix('jquery.min.js')} type="text/javascript" />
</Helmet>
```

Note the white spaces in the code, you should trail them.

If your assets are external third-party assets you can also import them in your `<Helmet>`, but without using `withPrefix` inner function. Just:

```
<Helmet>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type = "text / javascript" />
</Helmet>
```

Like any other component in React, your `<Helmet>` tag must be wrapped with something to avoid parsing issues, use it always like:

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Helmet>
      <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
    </Helmet>
  </Layout>
)
```